# Flutter.dev states that there is 96 Logical Pixels per inch, but it is around 134 in my device and emulators

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Flutter.dev states that there is 96 Logical Pixels per inch, but it is around 134 in my device and emulators. My device is:

2160px * 1080px
5.36in * 2.68in

Device pixel ratio = 3 so 403 pixels in one inch.
My device states that it has 360 * 720 logical pixels, so if we do the math there is 720/5.36=134 logical pixels per inch.

The question is: Is it variable or is it constant and 134. As I know it is 160 in android world, and according to flutter.dev web site it is 96.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Window/devicePixelRatio.html

> By definition, there are roughly 38 logical pixels per centimeter, or
>   about 96 logical pixels per inch, of the physical display. The value
>   returned by devicePixelRatio is ultimately obtained either from the
>   hardware itself, the device drivers, or a hard-coded value stored in
>   the operating system or firmware, and may be inaccurate, sometimes by
>   a significant margin.

Comment: Make your answer more formal to stay as per the community guidelines.

Comment: It's also 134 logical pixels per inch on my devices with different resolutions and screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

This is not precise, it's not really always 160 in android world. Devices are not forced to follow this, and they actually treat this as a design/marketing decision. For example, if they want to fit more stuff in the screen they will choose a DPI to achieve this effect. As a developer you have two options. First is to make a table per device, with the correct DPI you have to find out experimentally, and then convert from inches to pixels yourself. The second one is to forget about trying to know the exact DPI. Just make something approximate and accept the fact it's going to be slightly different in different devices.